# Прикольный современный слайдер

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Всем привет.
Вы скорее всего уже заметили во многих приложениях(vk, insta и др.) присутствует вот такие слайдеры.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Или же в живом примере на сайте [Apple com](http://www.apple.com/)

Как сделать такого рода слайдера? Или может есть такое в открытом доступе? Я просто не нашел.

Comment: Ето обичний слайдер в котором срабативает собитие через определенное время SetTimeout или SetInterval и паралельно менять розмер: закрашеной области елемента или  розмер елемента. Сооттветственно зделать ево цикличное прокручивание

Answer (score 1):

Частенько поглядывай в инструменты разработчика там и структуру можно глянуть и стили с js если видишь что то интересное на сайте.Комментарий **vov4ok** правильно все сказал.